# BLE Pairing on Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, pairing

I am working with a BLE device (which also has Bluetooth features).
I have to pair Android device with it. I use the `BluetoothDevice.createBond` to perform this action, and randomly the smartphone sends Ble pairing request or Bluetooth pairing request (seen on the device logs).
Is there a rule in the Android pairing process for the choice of the protocol used ?

I use a Honor 5C with Android 7 (very capricious with bluetooth...) and Nexus 6 also Android 7

Answer (score 1):

If you first use connectGatt with the transport parameter set to LE, then after the connection is complete you can pair over BLE.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, i was using default connect method (with auto mode) cause i am using rxAndroidBle and cannot change it. I am using the createBond(int transport) hidden method so and seems to work well. 
But I am curious to know if somebody have the algo or the working process of the auto mode